# Field null in extension class

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I created a WKWebView for use my App and I need that Swift talk to Javascript, everything is working except this!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var wk: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let user = WKUserContentController()

        user.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
        config.userContentController = user

        let wk = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        view.addSubview(wk)
   }   
}

extension FirstViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
            // HERE HAPPENS THE ERROR
            self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("chamaLista( '\(value!)' );", completionHandler: { (Any, Error) in })
        }
    }
}
```

This Error:
[image]

I add next code in didReceive function:

```
extension FirstViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
            if self.wk == nil {
                print("WK is Null!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:
[image]

Can't refering an object in extension class???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign the webview to `wk` in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    let wk = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    // assign the local variable to instance property
    self.wk = wk
    view.addSubview(wk)
}
```

or just:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    // assign directly to instance property, don't use local variable
    wk = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    view.addSubview(wk)
}
```

Comment: @Donadon In your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Uau.... ok! I excluded one part of code and that "let" was more! @Sulthan

Comment: Hey @Sulthan, I'm working straight into it and I did not see this silly mistake! Thank you!!!!!